# If I have a .js <script> in <Body> does .js get "called" automatically?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a .js Function run when the DOM is fully loaded by having my Function run when the Load event fires using jquery.

In the setup below, does the expander.js get called automatically (so it attaches the function to the click event) because it's linked in the  tag?
I put a Breakpoint in that function and it does not execute when I **click** the link. (So I thought maybe the function didn't get *attached* to the Click event.

**Setup:**

MyPage.html  has:
                  Expander

Learn more

Hidden-text-goes-here

```
<script src="scripts/expander.js" ></script> 
</body>
```

expander.js  is:

```
/* expander control */
$().ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-expander', function(e){
    var e =  e || event, 
        $el = $(this), 
        $content;

    e.preventDefault();

    $content = $el.parent().next('.js-expander-content')
    if ($content.length == 0)
      $content = $el.parent().parent().next('.js-expander-content')
      if ($content.length == 0)
        $content = $el.siblings('.js-expander-content');

    $content.slideToggle(150);
  })
})
```

Comment: Is that `$().ready` right? been a while since I jQuery..I thought it was `$(document).ready` or `$(function())`, what happens if you throw an alert("test") in the js file?

Comment: Because you are using `on('click'...)` I believe it is not called "automatically", only until you click the `document`

Comment: It should be called automatically as long as you include it in your html. Can you check in your console if you get any error? The syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: @GrayCygnus, thanks for noting that. My question was unclear. I meant "does the function *get attached*.  Clarified it.

Comment: @Dale The Alert does not execute. It looks like the issue is that my Anonymous function is not getting *attached* properly. Not sure why.

Comment: Please include your HTML. This code is dependent on an element like `<div class="js-expander"></div>`